# What type for a mpi4py communicator in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mpi, python-typing, mpi4py

I am using mpi4py to parallelize my code, I have this kind of function:

```
def do_something(some_integer: int, comm) -> None:
    ...
```

Where the `comm` argument is for an mpi communicator like the following:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
```

I want to use explicit typing for my functions and it is not clear to me what should be the type of the comm argument, *i.e.* what should come after `comm:` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly the [MPI documentation](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html)  that type should be:

```
mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm
```

So try it out with

```
def do_something(some_integer: int, comm: mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm) -> None:
```